# Dar permisos de lectura/escritura a una applet

Tags: java, aplicación-web, seguridad

Buenas, Tengo un mini-proyecto al cual quisiera darle permisos especiales a mi applet de lectura de un archivo que esta dentro de el servidor que lo contiene.

He visto que existen firmas para autenticar la seguridad de la aplicación y que corra sin problemas pero este proyecto tiene que estar disponible en la web para mostrarlo a un grupo de personas que carecen de conocimientos de manejo de seguridad.

También he visto que hay un tipo de archivo llamado applet.policy el cual otorga permisos, pero no se como relacionarlo con mi applet. ¿Pueden ayudarme?

Answer (score 1):

Los applets salieron en las 1ras versiones de java alla por 1995 y 1998 pero como se ejecutaban como plugins del navegador tenian grandes problemas de seguridad, he incluso su forma de programarse era un problema de seguridad, pues permitian al codigo del programador hacer cualquier cosa en la maquina cliente, incluso formatear la maquina (obvio con el conocimiento necesario).

Es por ello que aparecieron los servlets y luego los JSPs. Muchos programadores empezaron a usar los applets solo para instalar dll necesarias para su codigo. Pero dado los problemas que representa tener acceso a la maquina cliente y que ya existian servlets y jsps del lado del servidor, los navegadores empezaron a eliminar los plugins (incluido java y flash) y todo aquello basado en tecnologias NPAPI.

Actualmente el unico navegador que soporta el plugin de java es firefox, y mozilla a anunciado que lo va a eliminar al finalizar 2016, solo soportara flash y en un futuro tambien lo eliminara:
https://www.mozilla-hispano.org/el-f...pi-en-firefox/

Esto no significa que los navegadores dejen de soportar el lenguaje java como he leido en algunas paginas desinformadas. Los servlets y JSPs que son del lado del servidor siguen funcionando, por lo que deben cambiar sus aplicaciones de applets a servlets y JSPs, o a las alternativas de lado del cliente que ahora existen, o a los nuevos frameworks que trabajan sobre servlets y JSPs. Hay muchas alternativas: Javascript y AJAX (con todos los frameworks basados en ellos como AngularJS. Node.js, etc), HTML5, JavaFX, Java Web Start, etc.

No es posible que despues de que se vieran los problemas de seguridad de la tecnologia applet y saliera la alternativa, aun se siga utilizando casi 20 años despues. Hay que actualizarse y solo les queda el 2016 para hacerlo.

Saludos

Comment: "Esto no significa que los navegadores dejen de soportar el lenguaje Java" en realidad sí, de acuerdo al JEP 289 la api de Applet será deprecada en Java 9. Con esto ya no habría ninguna forma de ejecutar un Applet del lado del cliente (a menos no con las versiones nuevas de Java y en navegadores modernos). Usted menciona Servlet y JSP pero eso es exclusivamente del lado del servidor, un navegador web jamás tiene contacto con eso.

Comment: también mencione Javascript y AJAX (con todos los frameworks basados en ellos como AngularJS. Node.js,etc) incluso HTML5. Esa mención fue con un fin histórico, porque ahora se ha avanzado mas que eso.

Comment: Pero Javascript y AJAX no son tecnologías Java...

Comment: También comente alternativas java: JavaFX, Java Web Start, además si revisas esta liga en la sección
browsers encontraras los navegadores que soportan JavaFX, por lo que los navegadores siguen soportando java:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html